# Playing a sound from a dynamic generated list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and ASP.NET and I currently have a page that is dynamically displaying a list of .wav files from a directory using a checkbox list and displaying the date of the file when it was created. However since that is a .wav file I am trying to allow the end user to be able to play it but I am not sure where to start.

Any help will be appreciate it.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
if (filesDate > fromDate && filesDate < toDate)
{
    Response.Write("<input name=\"" + filePath + "\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + filePath +  \"/> <strong>Recording created on: " + filesDate + "</strong><br/>");                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something to play the wav files. Check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4943/MP3-Player-Server-Control

It basically contains a swf you can add the .wav files to.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the file in order for it be playable in the browser. [Here's an example.](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/ht/htsound.htm)

```
<object>
  <param name="autostart" value="true">
  <param name="src" value="eureka.wav">
  <param name="autoplay" value="true">
  <param name="controller" value="true">
  <embed src="eureka.wav" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
</object>
```

This is only one method. You can also use a flash player or some fancy html5 markup.